# Drupal wizard form: Validation and previous button

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-fapi, drupal-form-validation

In my drupal6 site I have wizard form. I implemented it with FormAPI using form storage and the rebuild property. My form validation is being done with the #required property and with functions in the #element_validate property. It's working fine but for one thing, when I click on the previous button the form is being validated and I don't want it to. Is there a smart and right way to disable the validations when a specific button of the form is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to do this cleanly (unfortunately) is to avoid the use of #required = TRUE and validate it yourself in a validation handler, taking into account knowledge of what 'step' the form is on in the wizard process.

One common approach is to accumulate all of your in-progress data in $form_state['storage'], where it will persist between rebuilds.

Comment: Thanks. I'm using the $form_state['storage']. Unfortunately I'll have to do what you said and implement a required validation function and then verify there if the user has clicked on the previous button and do not validate.

Answer (score 1):

```
  // hack to clear validation errors during wizard processing
  form_set_error(NULL, FALSE, TRUE);
  unset($_SESSION['messages']['error']);
```

Answer (score 1):

Kevin's answer works.  You could also try http://drupal.org/project/skip_validation where you would add an additional property to your previous button,`'#skip_validation' => TRUE`